# Copying an integer from GPU to CPU

Tags: cuda

I need to copy a single boolean or an integer value from the device to the host after every kernel call (I am calling the same kernel in a for loop). That is, after every kernel call, I need to send an integer or a boolean back to the host. What is the best way to do this?

Should I write the value directly to RAM? Or should I use cudaMemcpy()? Or is there any other way to do this? Would copying just 1 integer after every kernel launch slow down my program?

Answer (score 4):

Let me first answer your last question:

*Would copying just 1 integer after every kernel launch slow down my program?*

A bit - yes. Issuing the command, waiting for GPU to respond, etc, etc... The amount of data (1 int vs 100 ints) probably doesn't really matter in this case. However, you can still achieve speeds of thousands memory transfers per second. Most likely, your kernel will be slower than this single memory transfer (otherwise, it would be probably better to do the whole task on a CPU)

*what is the best way to do this?*

Well, I would suggest simply trying it yourself. As you said: you can either use mapped-pinned memory and have your kernel store the value directly to RAM, or use cudaMemcpy. The first one might be better if your kernels still have some work to do after sending the integer back. In that case, the latency of sending it to host could be hidden by the execution of the kernel.

If you use the first method, you will have to call `cudaThreadsynchronize()` to make sure the kernel ended its execution. Kernel calls are asynchronous.

You can use `cudaMemcpyAsync` which is also asynchronous, but GPU cannot have kernel running and having `cudaMemcpyAsync` executed in parallel, unless you use streams.

I never actually tried that, but if your program won't crash if the loop executes too many times, you *might* try to ignore synchronisation and let it iterate until the special value is seen in RAM. In that solution, the memory transfer might be completely hidden and you would pay an overhead only at the end. You will need however to somehow prevent the loop from iterating too many times, CUDA events may be helpful.

Comment: For copying single variables I advise using [cudaMemcpyFromSymbol](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g0b2cb4468ec7529fe24722f30e831a24.html#g0b2cb4468ec7529fe24722f30e831a24)

Comment: Agreed, `cudaMemcpyFromSymbol` is good to copy data to/from a global device variable (or constant). I don't think it is actually much faster than cudaMemcpy, but I haven't done any tests.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use pinned memory?  If your system supports it -- see CUDA C Programming Guide's section on pinned memory.

Answer (score 0):

Copying data to and from the GPU will be much slower than accessing the data from the CPU. If you are not running a significant number of threads for this value then this will result in very slow performance, don't do it.

What you are describing sounds like a serial algorithm, your algorithm needs to be parallelised in order to make it worth doing using CUDA. If you can't rewrite your algorithm to become a single write of multiple data to the GPU, multiple threads, single write of multiple data back to CPU; then your algorithm should be done on CPU.

Comment: I think it can be a serial algorithm which consists of complex parallel blocks inside.

Comment: @CygnusX1 If you had read my answer you would have seen that it accommodates that possibility.

Comment: The first paragraph, yes. But then you say "What you are describing sounds like a serial algorithm" --- I have faced similar problem as the question author many times, despite my programs being highly parallel. Hence my comment.

Comment: @CynusX1 And if you had read my second paragraph you would have seen "..single write, *multiple threads*,..". We have all faced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the value computed in the previous kernel call to launch the next one then is serialized and your choice is to **cudaMemcpy(dst,src, size =1, ...);**

If all the kernel launch parameters do not depend on the previous launch then you can store all the result of each kernel invocation in GPU memory and then download all the results at once.